# android image display app code

Tags: android-studio

I am a beginner in android application development and I was going through an app to display images in app and I was unable to understand the following piece of code..can anyone explain??

```
imageIndex++;
            imageIndex=imageIndex% images.length;
            iv.setImageResource(images[imageIndex]);
```

why do we need to write ImageIndex% images.length?

Comment: got no proper question title?

Answer (score 0):

This is to ensure that you access the "images" array out of bounds. imageIndex should not exceed the array size. This is nothing specific to Android or images, just basic programming concept.